# Can Someone Explain PPC Branch Link

Tags: assembly, powerpc

I am fairly new to PPC assembly, and I am interested in how the compiler encodes the branch link.

Example:

```
00000000 fnc_1()
00000000 std r1 , 0x7FFFF
00000004 li r2 , 0x0
00000008 mr r3 , r2
*** -> 0000000C bl fnc_2 -> | 10010 | ?? 24bits ?? | 0 | 1 | ****
00000010 blr

00000014 fnc_2()
00000014 ..
00000018 ..
0000001C ..
00000020 blr
```

So, my question boils down to: **How does the compiler take the offset 0x14, and transform it into the 24bits in the bl opcode.**  I have looked at programs in hex but still cant figure it out.  I have read this: http://www.eecs.umich.edu/eecs/courses/eecs373/GreenBook/ch4-bran.pdf
Any clarification would help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the PPC ISA [(PDF Link)](http://moss.csc.ncsu.edu/~mueller/cluster/ps3/SDK3.0/docs/arch/PPC_Vers202_Book1_public.pdf), `bl` is:

```
bits    value
0-5     18
6-29    LI
30      AA (0)
31      LK (1)
```

The `LK` bit being set indicates that the next instruction address should be placed into the link register.  When `AA` is `0`, the branch target address is the sum of `LI << 2`, sign extended, with the address of the current instruction.  So for you, since you want to jump to `0x14` and the current location is `0xC`, you just want to put `0x14 - 0xC == 0x8` into the register.  Chopping off the two bottom zeroes (to account for the instruction doing the opposite operation at runtime) leaves you with an encoding `LI == 0x2`.  So finally, the encoding is:

```
  18               LI            AA  LK
 10010 000000000000000000000010  0    1
```

Comment: What is the purpose of putting the next instruction following the `bl` in the link register? Why is the `bl <next instruction>` *not* omitted so the code just "falls" into the next instruction?

Comment: That's the return address, not the jump destination that's going in the link register. I'm not sure I follow your question.